I can't get sorting to work using "Out-GridView" output
At work, we are asked to log the exact time in a time sheet. I found this online to help me out (instead of going through Windows logs):
wevtutil qe Security /q:"*[System[(EventID=4800 or EventID=4801)]]" /f:Text |
    findstr "Date" | Out-GridView

This works fine but I can't seem to find the right way to sort the output reversed alphabetical order.
I tried changing:
findstr "Date" | Out-GridView

to:
findstr "Date" | Sort "Date" -Descending | Out-GridView

(with or witout quotes on Date). The results always come out as unsorted.
Any clues as to why that is?

It's hard to understand what output you would like to see. Nevertheless, I would suggest to write the command fully in Powershell like this:
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security'; Id=4800, 4801} | Out-GridView

This will get the Event log in Powershell object form, which will enable you to sort as you wish in Out-GridView (ogv). The command you are using has text output and is not really suitable to pipe into ogv.

wevtutil.exe returns STRINGS, not objects.
Out-GridView and Sort-Object have thus no Properties they can use to sort them.
You can either:

work aound that by extract and convert data and properties from the string output.
It's a hassle and not worth it because you can...
just use Get-WinEvent as suggested by @repic

